# How to make Bootstrap header that changes size on scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've seen a few different threads seemingly about this but none of the answers in them have a working solution for me.

Here's what I want:

- Big transparent header with a big logo on the top.
- Small colored header with a small logo when user has scrolled past the topmost area.

I'm using `navbar-fixed-top` and and Bootstrap's scrollspy to add and remove certain classes from the header.

Here's why it hasn't worked so far:

- `$(window).scrollTop()` doesn't return anything meaningful at all.
- It seems wrong to change at a certain amount of pixels from the top anyway, since it can vary between screen resolutions.
- Initiating a change based on what `activate.bs.scrollspy` captures works rather well except it shows the wrong header when I load the page for the first time.
- It seems impossible to place a `<div id="whatever">` at a certain spot and have the header change when scrollspy finds it. I've tried making the div 1px in dimension and placed at the absolute top of the page, but the scrollspy still identifies it from way off.

Here's my jQuery code at the moment, which is very imprecise AND shows the wrong header at the first load of the page (remember, you're not always at the top of the page when loading (reloading) the page!).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.navbar-inverse' });

$('#main-header').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {

    var currentItem = $('.nav li.active > a').text();
    var header = $('.navbar');
    var logosmall = $('.small-brand');
    var logobig = $('.big-brand');

    if (currentItem == 'top' && header.hasClass('navbar-small')) {
        header.removeClass('navbar-small');
    header.addClass('navbar-big');
    logosmall.css('display', 'none');
    logobig.css('display', 'inline-block');
}

    else if (currentItem != 'top' && header.hasClass('navbar-big')) {
        header.removeClass('navbar-big');
        header.addClass('navbar-small');
        logobig.css('display', 'none');
        logosmall.css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code into window scroll event as mentioned below then only $(window).scrollTop() will work as you expecting.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {});
```

Comment: What about when loading/reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great example of your problem, it is a bit tricky to shrink your navbar but not impossible. You have to take into account a lot of things. I found this a while ago: http://www.bootply.com/109943

It is really strange that `$(window).scrollTop()` does not return anything by the way. What browser are you on? And your problem with reloading the browser:

`$(window).load(function{
//logic to check how far scrolled 
})`